# Data flow: Azure Event Hubs to Cosmos db VS Cosmos db to Azure Event Hub - Better option?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I want to monitor some events coming from my application.

One option is to send data to Azure Event Hub and use stream analytics to do some post-processing and enter the data into cosmos db.

Another option is to store to cosmos db from application and run a periodic azure function to do the processing and store it back.

What is the right way to do it? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The best architecture way is to have Event Hubs to Cosmos DB. I have done the same implementations using `Application -> EventHub -> ChangeFeed Azure Function -> Cosmosdb`

You can read about [`Here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed).

Answer (score 1):

ChangeFeed is offered by Azure Cosmos DB out of the box for this case. It works as a trigger on Cosmos DB change.

Comment: that is the answer mentioned below. what is different?

Comment: your answer is not clear. Event hub is not required here, changeFeed itself will trigger the Azure Function.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of processing that you would like to do with the events ingested. If it is *event at a time* processing, a simple Azure Function with CosmosDB changefeed processor might be enough. If you would like to do stateful processing like [windowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/windowing-azure-stream-analytics) or [event order based computation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/analytic-functions-azure-stream-analytics), azure Stream Analytics would be better. Stream Analytics also provides native integration to PowerBI dashboards. Same job can send the data both to CosmosDB and PowerBI. If you are going to use Azure Stream Analytics, you will have to use EventHub for event ingestion. Using EventHub for ingestion also has other benefits like being able to [archive events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview) to blob storage.